# Is there any Torah source for the phrase "עם ישראל חי"?

Tags: am-yisrael-jewish-nation

Is there any Torah source for the phrase famous words used in the song "**עם ישראל חי**"?

I don't mean the concept of the perseverance of the Jewish nation etc.. I mean these exact words.

Comment: I suspect with minimal effort you could do a tremendously better job at sourcing and motivating this question. See for instance https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3684/759 As shown by the answer below, this post also shows a distinct lack of any research effort.

Answer (score 4):

A quick [search](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%97%D7%99&var=0&sort=r&lang=bi) of [Sefaria.org](http://sefaria.org) reveals that there are 0 results for those exact words. Therefore, it is safe to say that those words are not mentioned in Tanakh, Talmud, Midrash, Halacha, Kabbala, and all the other Sefarim that are included in the search.

Comment: I did that search myself too, I was wondering if there may be a source in somewhere not part of that program. Thank you anyway for your effort.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore If you had just included that information in your question then you would have prevented aBochur from wasting his valuable time repeating your efforts. Please please please start writing better question posts!

Answer (score 3):

I found the following (and added in the bolding):
The Alei Tamar on Brachot 9

אגב הנני לרשום שמתוך דחף פנימי על קרב מלחמת ה' של בנינו הצעירים חביבי האומה ותפארתה נגד אויבנו אשר אמרו לכו ונכחידם מגוי ולא יזכר שם ישראל עוד חלילה, ובמלחמתם מנשרים קלו ומאריות גברו לשם קיום האומה ביום שמחת תורה שעה שהתורה והאומה היו שרוים בצער אין סופי עליהם, עלה על רעיוני והוצאתי לפועל שהקפה שביעית הקפת דוד מלך ישראל שלחם בעד חרות ישראל יהיה קודש להם ולמפקדיהם הלוחמים בעד ארץ ישראל וערי ישראל ותורת ישראל ובשליחותם עשינו הקפת דוד מלך ישראל בעדם, שאכן בוודאי התורה ודוד מלך ישראל כואבים ושמחים בשמחתם שיזכו בניצחון על אויבנו בנפש שעל זה חרפו נפשם למות ושפכו את דמם ובדמם חי עם ישראל **עם ישראל חי**.

and
The Sh"ut of the Mayim Chayim, 1:69

ובכן, זו אמת לפי משנה זאת, וגם הסברו של הרמב"ם נכון (אף כי נוכיח להלן שאין כן הלכה). ודבר זה היה מובן היטב, ואף כיום יכול להיות מובן היטב בחברה מאמינה בתורה מן השמים ושומרת מצוות, ואנסה להסביר:
  פעמים רבות נאמר בתנ"ך שעל ידי קיום תורה ומצוות אלה, **עם ישראל חי** ומתקיים, ובנין אב לכל המקראות האלה הוא: ואתם הדבקים בה' אלקיכם חיים כלכם היום (דברים ד' ד').

The 7 references to "Od Avinu Chai" were all pointing to a particularly named siddur.

Comment: Shut Mayim Chayim is by R Yosef Messas https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A9

Comment: @rosends Might you kindly share with me the name of the program which you used for your serch?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore I used the Bar Ilan Online Responsa Project